# Use curl with a webpage with no security protocol

Tags: c, linux, windows, curl, protocols

I have a webpage: 10.1.1.165 that I am trying to get the data off of. I have built this program in linux and it works fine, however, when developing for windows systems I am running into an issue.

```
    if (filename.substr(filename.length() - 4, 4) == "html" || filename.substr(filename.length() - 3, 3) == "htm") 
    {
        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res;
        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        string s;

        if (curl)
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, filename.c_str());

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);

            if (gLogger->isDebug()) curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); 

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout/1000);

                //curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); //remove this to disable verbose output


            // Perform the request, res will get the return code 
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

            // Check for errors 
            if (res != CURLE_OK)
            {
                while (res == CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT)
                {
                    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                }

                if (res != CURLE_OK)
                {
                    gLogger->error("curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
                    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

On my linux system, this works perfectly. On my Windows system I get: curl_easy_perform() failed: Unsupported protocol. If I go to my webpage 10.1.1.165 I see that it is being hosted with NO security. I have no way of changing how that webpage is being hosted.

Per this resource: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS.html

> By default libcurl will accept all protocols

Does anyone know why curl doesn't like me grabbing this webpage on windows? And if so, what settings might I have to adjust?

Comment: adding this line does not change anything: ```curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_ALL);```

Comment: `filename.substr(filename.length() - 4, 4) == "html"` doesn't look like C

Comment: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, filename.c_str())` - what is the value of `filename.c_str()` ?

Comment: @qrdl yes sorry, this is embedded in a c++ program.

Comment: @qrdl filename = "10.1.1.165/index.htm". This is valid and works on my linux machine.

Comment: @qrdl I don't know why you downvoted the curl package I'm implementing is C.

Comment: `10.1.1.165` is not a valid URL, as it has no scheme. Without a scheme curl will guess which one you meant. In this case plain HTTP. If your libcurl doesn't support that, it was built with HTTP disabled - a fairly unusual setup. Unless you happened to also have garbage somewhere in the string or similar.

Comment: @B.Hoeper `filename = "10.1.1.165/index.htm". This is valid` No this is not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Comment: @qrdl my question is then why is it working on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by switching to curl-7.55.1. Previously I was using curl-7.68.0. I'm not sure if the functionality was removed or if using it is more involved.